# How much does it cost to declare war on a settlement and take control of it?

Tags: new-world

If an opposing faction controls a settlement, and you have enough influence in the area to declare war on the settlement with your company:

How much does it cost to declare war on the settlement?

And how much does it cost to take control of the settlement after you win the war?

Just curious how much gold a company needs to take control of a settlement that is already under an opposing faction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare [War](https://newworld.wiki.fextralife.com/War) the cost depends on the Tier of War Camp you decide on.

Your options are:

1: Normal Gate Strength, Deployment Limit of 6, Normal Siege Supply Rate, 7,500 Gold

2: High Gate Strength, Deployment Limit of 8, High Siege Supply Rate, 10,000 Gold

3: Highest Gate Strength, Deployment Limit of 10, Highest Siege Supply Rate, 15,00 Gold

> The **Gate Strength** refers to the War Camp gate's integrity or "health".
> **Deployment Limit** refers to the amount of Siege Platforms that can be
> deployed at any one time. Keep in mind that attacker Siege Platforms
> can be picked up and moved around and will not count towards the
> Deployment Limit if they are not on the battlefield. **Siege Supply** is a
> resource generated at the Attackers' War Camp and Defenders' Fort used
> to repair structures such as gates, as well as Siege Weapons.

> **If the attacking army prevails, they will now have control over the
> Territory and everything within it**. The defeated party will have lost
> their Settlement and Fort, as well as all their Territorial Bonuses.
> These can be earned back through another War declaration but the
> Company would have to first regroup. After a War's conclusion, there
> is a cooldown period before another War can be declared against that
> territory.

Note: It costs nothing to the attackers afterwards to claim the territory. The only territory claim cost is on the initial company purchase of an unclaimed territory which costs 100,000 Gold.